# Rcpp subsetting rows of DataFrame

Tags: r, rcpp

I wished to create a following subset of the `iris` dataset using the `Rcpp` package:

```
head(subset(iris, Species == "versicolor"))

  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
51          7.0         3.2          4.7         1.4 versicolor
52          6.4         3.2          4.5         1.5 versicolor
53          6.9         3.1          4.9         1.5 versicolor
54          5.5         2.3          4.0         1.3 versicolor
55          6.5         2.8          4.6         1.5 versicolor
56          5.7         2.8          4.5         1.3 versicolor
```

I know how to subset columns of `Rcpp::DataFrame` - there is an overloaded operator `[` which works as in R: `x["var"]`. However, I cannot find any way that would allow me to subset rows of a DataFrame with a not fixed number of columns.

I would like to write a function `subset_rows_rcpp_iris` which takes `Rcpp::DataFrame` (which will always be iris) and a `CharacterVector level_of_species` as inputs. It will return `DataFrame` object.

```
DataFrame subset_rows_rcpp_iris(DataFrame x, CharacterVector level_of_species) {
    ...
}
```

First, I want to find indices of rows that satisfy logical query. My problem is that if I access the `Species` vector in `test` function, save it as a `CharacterVector` and then compare it with `level_of_species` I get always only one `TRUE` value in case of `setosa` and FALSE values in other cases.

```
cppFunction('
    LogicalVector test(DataFrame x, CharacterVector level_of_species) {
            CharacterVector sub = x["Species"];
            LogicalVector ind = sub == level_of_species;
            return(ind);
            }
')
head(test(iris, "setosa"))

[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

If this worked, I could rewrite `test` function and use the vector with TRUE/FALSE values to subset each of the column of the data frame separately and then combine them again with `Rcpp::DataFrame::create`.

Comment: Yes, indeed. However, I don't know how can I represent a character scalar in C++. There is no such a class as `CharacterScalar` in Rcpp. `String` doesn't work either.

Comment: right right!! my mistake..since there was NumericScalar i thought the same here....i think we are assuming recylcing of R in C++ here when doing sub==level_of_species

Comment: we need to have a for loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
cppFunction('LogicalVector test(DataFrame x, StringVector level_of_species) {
  using namespace std;  
  StringVector sub = x["Species"];
  std::string level = Rcpp::as<std::string>(level_of_species[0]);
  Rcpp::LogicalVector ind(sub.size());
  for (int i = 0; i < sub.size(); i++){
      ind[i] = (sub[i] == level);
  }

  return(ind);
}')

xx=test(iris, "setosa")
> table(xx)
 xx
 FALSE  TRUE 
   100    50
```

---

Subsetting done!!! (i myself learnt a lot from this question..thanks!)

```
cppFunction('Rcpp::DataFrame test(DataFrame x, StringVector level_of_species) {
  using namespace std;  
  StringVector sub = x["Species"];
  std::string level = Rcpp::as<std::string>(level_of_species[0]);
  Rcpp::LogicalVector ind(sub.size());
  for (int i = 0; i < sub.size(); i++){
    ind[i] = (sub[i] == level);
  }

 // extracting each column into a vector
 Rcpp::NumericVector   SepalLength = x["Sepal.Length"];
 Rcpp::NumericVector   SepalWidth = x["Sepal.Width"];
 Rcpp::NumericVector PetalLength = x["Petal.Length"];
 Rcpp::NumericVector   PetalWidth = x["Petal.Width"];


 return Rcpp::DataFrame::create(Rcpp::Named("Sepal.Length")  = SepalLength[ind],
                                Rcpp::Named("Sepal.Width")  = SepalWidth[ind],
                                Rcpp::Named("Petal.Length")  = PetalLength[ind],
                                Rcpp::Named("Petal.Width")  = PetalWidth[ind]
);}')

yy=test(iris, "setosa")
> str(yy)
 'data.frame':  50 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ Sepal.Length: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
 $ Sepal.Width : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
 $ Petal.Length: num  1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
 $ Petal.Width : num  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
```