# Omitting the rows of a data frame in which their elements are the same

Tags: r, rcpp

Let's say we have a data frame like this

```
DataFrame ref = DataFrame::create( Named("sender") = sender , Named("receiver") = receiver);
```

the corresponding R code is as follows:

```
edge <- as.data.frame(edge) %>%
set_colnames(c("time", "sender", "receiver"))
edge <- rbind(c(0,0,0), edge)
ref  <- data.frame(sender = rep(1:n, times = n),
                receiver = rep(1:n, each = n)

 ) %>%
filter(sender != receiver) %>%
mutate(teller = 1:(n*(n-1)))
```

Some rows in this data frame have the same elements, say, 2     2, I want to find them and remove them from the data frame. Then I want to add another column to this data frame which is like numbers from 1 to the number of row of the new data frame.

Example:

[image: Please see here]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  It sounds like you want to learn `data.table`. You will likely get the same performance without having to learn or write compiled code.  Also, a mock data set and example output (maybe in slower R code?) would make your question more powerful and likely attract better answers.

Comment: @Mori I suppose `ref` here is the example data set, but something Dirk Eddelbuettel mentioned that would be really helpful that still isn't up would be example *output*. The operation you're wanting to do isn't fully clear (at least to me), but could be clearer with if you show the output you'd expect from the mock data set.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel  thanks. I edited the question and add one numerical example as you suggested. Now please see whether it is clear  you can give me  a bit more concrete answer.

Comment: It seems to me you are *very* unlikely to beat base R, or something like `data.table`, with `Rcpp` when your task is subsetting the rows of a data frame. There are lots of situations where you can get better performance with `Rcpp`, but I don't think this is one of them.

Comment: @Mori:  You "didn't add an example". You added a link to an image. In short: "Don't do that.".  StackOverflow prefers an actual example you may see in other posts you visit.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this question could be construed as a duplicate of [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40691823/8386140), but I answer here separately to demonstrate my point in the comments, that if you're doing this for performance gains, `Rcpp` may not be the way to go for this *particular* task. That is, there are many tasks where `Rcpp` would be my go to for increased performance, but subsetting rows of data frames is not one of those tasks.

The code is pretty easy to set up, following the approach from the answer I linked:

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::DataFrame foo(Rcpp::DataFrame x) {
    Rcpp::NumericVector sender = x["sender"];
    Rcpp::NumericVector receiver = x["receiver"];
    Rcpp::LogicalVector indices = sender != receiver;
    return Rcpp::DataFrame::create(Rcpp::Named("sender") = sender[indices],
                                   Rcpp::Named("receiver") = receiver[indices]);
}
```

**But**, we can see that the speed of execution of this is actually *worse* than base R (and `data.table` can *slightly* edge out the performance of base R):

```r
library(dplyr)
library(Rcpp)
library(microbenchmark)
library(data.table)

sourceCpp("so.cpp")

for ( n in 10^(1:3) ) {
    ref  <- data.frame(sender = rep(1:n, times = n),  ## If you're using
                       receiver = rep(1:n, each = n)) ## data frames
    refDT <- setDT(ref) ## If you're using data.table
    cat("For n =", n, "(a data frame with", nrow(ref), "rows)\n")
    print(microbenchmark(base = ref[ref$sender != ref$receiver, ],
                         dplyr = ref %>% filter(sender != receiver),
                         rcpp = foo(ref),
                         data.table = refDT[sender != receiver]))
    cat("\n")
}
```

```
For n = 10 (a data frame with 100 rows)
Unit: microseconds
       expr     min       lq     mean   median       uq     max neval
       base 123.917 140.0025 160.7615 155.1905 170.7825 302.520   100
      dplyr 397.308 430.7595 478.0543 446.9185 492.5705 900.716   100
       rcpp 189.473 212.9530 238.8270 223.3305 240.7950 461.452   100
 data.table 122.436 135.9185 160.6607 154.0565 166.7825 460.739   100

For n = 100 (a data frame with 10000 rows)
Unit: microseconds
       expr     min       lq     mean   median       uq     max neval
       base 205.978 224.9760 250.7321 244.3315 265.5060 510.079   100
      dplyr 519.276 581.4535 629.2837 615.7095 662.8060 989.698   100
       rcpp 369.276 430.3510 463.1586 471.3195 486.4450 736.907   100
 data.table 198.012 221.8445 248.9371 246.2385 267.5325 341.935   100

For n = 1000 (a data frame with 1000000 rows)
Unit: milliseconds
       expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq      max
       base  6.535990  6.892702  7.664697  7.203983  7.554144 11.42160
      dplyr  8.795884  9.239173 10.024997  9.618395  9.992066 15.04914
       rcpp 15.116928 15.598556 17.164895 16.216766 17.066418 30.45578
 data.table  6.624728  6.905202  7.543284  7.137171  7.482922 11.67061
 neval
   100
   100
   100
   100
```

Comment: Fantastic work.  Now I can finally go around telling people to use base R because it is faster than `Rcpp` anyway :)  Or, as I usually do (see first comment above) to use `data.table` which most likely beats the socks of all of'em.

Comment: Kidding aside not sure why we suck there.  There must be one other memory allocation and copy in the `Rcpp::DataFrame` case.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Yeah, `data.table` is pretty underrated for fast data wrangling! The `DataFrame` case is just a particular hard case for `Rcpp`, I think you're right it has to do with the memory allocation, but not sure what `data.table` is doing under the hood... May take a look at the source one day if my curiosity level and free time levels both go up

Comment: Thank you @duckmayr foe clear answer. I leaned many things here.

Comment: Thank you @DirkEddelbuettel for your comments.

Comment: please use `as.data.table` instead of `setDT` in that context, and of course re-run benchmark, you may eventually find base R slightly faster than it is now

Comment: why it may be faster: 1. `subsetDT`, exported at C level for other packages to use, is parallelized, it takes row indices already, using `setDTthreads(0)` to use all cores may speed it up even more, bc DT uses 50% cores by default. 2. as of now we cannot optimize `sender != receiver` to binary search (due to `!=` op), so it is all I can think of now.

Comment: one more advice is to scale it up to get measures in seconds, rather than micro/mili s, where the "parsing" query overhead pollute the timings of actual subset operation. You can use `times = 10` in microbenchmark rather than default 100.